# ImageMagick identify landscape images with no exif data

Tags: batch-file, cmd, imagemagick

I have a several JPEG images with no exif data sized 1080x1920 and 1920x1080. I need to identify only the ones in 1920x1080.

Tried to use

```
identify -size 1920x1080 *.jpg
```

but it also lists the portrait versions. Is there a way around, possibly using Windows Batch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In good, old-fashioned, Windows XP and older, and newer batch, you can do something like this to print the width then height then image names of all JPEG files, separated by colons:

```
identify -format "%w:%h:%f\n" *.jpg
```

Then you can pick the ones matching your width and height requirements in a FOR loop like this with `FINDSTR`:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=:" %A in ('identify -format "%w:%h:%f\n" *.jpg ^| findstr "1920:1080"') do echo %C
```

If you use a BATCH file, rather than the command line prompt, you have to replace all percent signs with double percent signs for some illogical reason only Microsoft could come up with - sorry!

Comment: You need double percent signs because for some reason, you use percent signs to escape percent signs, which is weird because the escape character for most other symbols in batch is ^.

Answer (score 0):

With windows [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) you would iterate over the JPEG files, and only act on the ones that match the dimensions that match a common pattern.

```ps
# Set environment path (so we can use `identify.exe` from program files.)
$env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine")

# Iterate over "images" directory for jpeg
Get-ChildItem C:\images -Filter *.jpg | Foreach-Object {
    # Only print image dimension WIDTHxHEIGHT
    $size=identify.exe -format '%wx%h' $_.FullName
    if ($size -eq "1920x1080") {
         # Match! print out filename
        echo $_.FullName
    }
}
```